# Convert D:HH:MM:SS (text) to Days (dec) in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

When adding a custom column in Power BI, is there a way of making that column calculated from a text D:HH:MM:SS column, to a decimal "Days" column?

The raw data I have in the CSV, is in text format (first column), should end up having a calculated column of Days:

[image: Text to Days]

If there's not a calculation, is it possible to parse the text of the first column into D, H, M, S and then calculate Days from the resulting text?

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to [split the column by delimiter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/split-columns-delimiter) (colon in this case)

[image]

to get separate columns for days, hours, minutes and seconds:

[image]

And then add a [custom column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-add-custom-column) using this formula:

```
[Text.1] + ([Text.2]/24) + ([Text.3]/1440) + ([Text.4]/86400)
```

[image]

to calculate the decimal duration:

[image]

Of course, you can delete these columns later if you don't need them, or you can rename them to something more meaningful if you decide to keep them.